# Google Event Tracking on <p> clicks

Tags: events, tracking

I am looking to implement Google Event Tracking on a new website and couldn't find any documentation on this, but basically I just need to confirm that I add the standard 'onClick="_gaq.push([...' to a paragraph tag (which I have a jQuery event on already), the event tracking will still function as it would on an

Comment: on an...? Why not try it? Anyway, I would advise against adding an onclick attribute to each paragraph, but yes, you can track that way.